# Capturar excepciones en Función de Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Necesito que cuando en una función se genere una excepción definida de postgres poderla guardar en una tabla, básicamente necesito capturar la excepción, guardarla en una variable, para pasarla como parámetro en los values del insert

Este es mi código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.prueba(par numeric)
    RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ declare 

msg varchar(100);

begin
    select lf.respuesta_funcion into msg from log_funciones lf where id = par;
    return msg;
exception when others then
    insert into log_funciones (nombre_funcion, respuesta_funcion, usuario_generador) values ('public.prueba', msg, 'b');
    return 'Se realizó la insersión del exception';
END;
$function$
;
```

Comment: Qué sucede cuando ejecutas ese código?

Comment: A la tabla a lque le hago el SELECT no tiene registros, entonces en el return me devuelve un NULL, pero no entra en la excepción

Comment: Entonces, eso no es problema de insertar sino de levantar una excepción. Lo que describes no genera ninguna de las excepciones predefinidas por PostgreSQL y este código alegremente devolverá NULL.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que se genera una excepción y poderla capturar y guardar en la tabla??

Comment: Ya cambié el bloque de excepción en el código de la respuesta. Revisa si te sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que realmente buscas, necesitas lanzar una excepción en tu lógica que te lleve a la sección EXCEPTION del bloque plpgsql. Asignarle NULL a una variable no genera ese resultado.

Además de las excepciones predefinidas por PGSQL, es posible lanzar excepciones propias si se cumple alguna condición que uno defina. En tu caso:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.prueba(par numeric)
    RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ declare 

msg varchar(100);

begin
    select lf.respuesta_funcion into msg from log_funciones lf where id = par;

    IF msg ISNULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid value: %', msg USING HINT = 'NULL values not accepted for msg';
    END IF;

    return msg;
exception when others then
    insert into log_funciones (nombre_funcion, respuesta_funcion, usuario_generador) 
    values ('public.prueba', SQLERRM, 'b');
    return 'Se realizó la insersión del exception';
END;
$function$
;
```

Comment: Se genera la inserción que se tiene en el exception pero no me genera el mensaje del RAISE EXCEPTION, que pena, es que soy nuevo en postgres. Muchas gracias

Comment: @BrysonStevenMosqueraFlorez no entiendo. Buscabas que hiciera la inserción, no? Necesitas también ver el mensaje? Ese depende de la configuración que tengas para mostrar mensajes en la salida estándar

Comment: Si, realiza la inserción, solo creí que se debía mostrar ese mensaje también, por qué eso sería una excepción personalizada, cierto??

Comment: @BrysonStevenMosqueraFlorez El mensaje va a salir por salida estándar de PGSQL. No va a quedar en tu log de aplicación. Si usas un cliente como Toad, pgAdmin o similar, puedes usar `set client_min_messages = 'debug';` ANTES de correr lo que sea que use tu función para garantizar que salgan todos los mensajes.

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda, ese código del comentario anterior iría al inicio de mi función??

Comment: @BrysonStevenMosqueraFlorez lo usarías apenas inicias sesión. No es código para integrar en un script o en una tarea automatizada. Sirve para que tú, humano, veas el mensaje del raise.

Comment: Vale, como hago para guardar una excepción predefinida de Postgres?? Muchas gracias. es que tengo que tener esos dos escenarios cubiertos

Comment: @BrysonStevenMosqueraFlorez Por favor edita la pregunta si necesitas añadir información adicional y así yo puedo editar la respuesta con lo que haga falta. En tu comentario no se entiende qué es lo adicional que necesitas

Comment: Vale, ya realice la modificación a la pregunta. Muchas gracias